# How to remove a key value pair from object while updating values of remaining objects?

Tags: javascript

```js
const initialState = {
    loading: null,
    error: null,
    lineItems: [
         {
             id: 1, 
             product_name: "Elbow 15", 
             product_disc: 1, 
             sub_total: 5548.95, 
             product_unit: "Nos", 
             …
         }
         {
             id: 2, 
             product_name: "Tee 15", 
             product_disc: 3, 
             sub_total: 24.25, 
             product_unit: "Nos", 
             …
         }
         {
             id: 3, 
             product_name: "", 
             product_disc: 0, 
             sub_total: 0
         }
    ]
```

`lineItems` represent rows in a grid (I am using react-data-grid)

`id` property values are used to populate the first column ("Serial Number") of the grid

If a user deletes a row (e.g. middle object in the above case),
how to update the above object, so that is becomes

```js
  lineItems: [
        {
            id: 1, 
            product_name: "Elbow 15", 
            product_disc: 1, 
            sub_total: 5548.95, 
            product_unit: "Nos", 
            …
        }
        {
            id: 2, 
            product_name: "", 
            product_disc: 0, 
            sub_total: 0
        }
    ]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an object with numeric keys instead of an array? If it were an array you could use `splice()` to remove elements.

Comment: why you need `id:3` to `id:2` after delete? Id should not be changed I guess.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks that helps with removing the item. Maybe, have to use a loop to update the id property value

Comment: @Tuhim to update the serial number column in react-data-grid. The user wouldn't want missing serial numbers in his grid

Comment: isn't it easier to hide the row, and update the ids when the data is needed

Comment: @Slai I do not understand. Let me rephrase. The 'id' column is a serial number column for the user.  When a user views the grid, he would never want missing numbers. If I hide the row, there would be a missing number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delete` to remove a property from an object. Then you'll need to loop through the remaining properties and update their keys and the `id` properties within them.

```js
function removeLineItem(state, index) {
  delete state.lineItems[index];
  Object.keys(state.lineItems).forEach(k => {
    if (state.lineItems[k].id > index) {
      state.lineItems[k].id = k - 1; // decrement id
      state.lineItems[k - 1] = state.lineItems[k]; // decrement key
      delete state.lineItems[k]; // remove old key
    }
  });
}

const initialState = {
  loading: null,
  error: null,
  lineItems: {
    0: {
      id: 1,
      product_name: "Elbow 15",
      product_disc: 1,
      sub_total: 5548.95,
      product_unit: "Nos",
    },
    1: {
      id: 2,
      product_name: "Tee 15",
      product_disc: 3,
      sub_total: 24.25,
      product_unit: "Nos",
    },
    2: {
      id: 3,
      product_name: "",
      product_disc: 0,
      sub_total: 0
    }
  }
};

removeLineItem(initialState, 1);
console.log(initialState);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delete keyword to delete specific key from your object.

```
delete object['key']
```